# Examples of varieties with torsion in their integral Hodge structure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, abelian-varieties

I am not so used to thinking about integral Hodge structures, so this question might be completely trivial.

What are easy and interesting examples of smooth projective connected varieties $X$ with torsion in their integral Hodge structure?

The Hodge structures arising from abelian varieties have torsion coming from the torsion points on the abelian variety.

I am looking for varieties with torsion in their integral Hodge structure which can't be explained (directly) via abelian varieties (somehow).

Answer (score 2):

The integral cohomology of an abelian variety is torsion-free, so I'm not sure what you mean about them having torsion in their integral Hodge structure.

---

There are examples of smooth projective surfaces having torsion in their integral $H^2$.  (The examples I know best arise as Shimura varieties, but there are examples 
in other contexts too, e.g. Enriques surfaces.  See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/51317) for more discussion.)

---

There will be lots of higher dimensional examples too, but it can be hard to find 
them discussed explicitly in the literature.